# La carpeta de VENV no aparece

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

Desinstalé virtualenv y al instalarlo de nuevo con `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv virtualenv` se instala normalmente, pero la carpeta de env no aparece en ninguna parte.

Luego intenté instalarlo con `pip install virtualenv` y me dice que no tengo permisos, así que procedí a hacerlo con sudo `sudo pip install virtualenv` pero ahí me arrojó el siguiente problema `sudo: pip: orden no encontrada`

Answer (score 0):

prueba con:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, intente con todas las alternativas :(

Comment: has instalado el pip3 `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` antes y tampoco?

Comment: Sí, de hecho incluso lo desinstalé y lo volví a instalar